# Making a background larger when page is smaller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Is there a possibility to when you make a webpage smaller (for example on tablets or phones) the background stretches. So the text is still in de same area as before?

Answer (score 2):

You can make any CSS style you want to be applied only on specific screen size.

```
<style>
  @media screen (min-width:400px){
   div {background-position:center} //This style will be applied only to screen larger than 400px
  }
</style>
```

Create the CSS you want for each device, and surround it by the right `@media` you need.

More Info:

- [CSS media rule on W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)
- You can test it, without real device, by reszing the window, or using [Chrome Inspector Device Emulation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for :

```
background-size: contain;
```

> ### contain
>
> A keyword that scales the image as large as possible and maintains image aspect ratio (image doesn't get squished). Image is letterboxed within the container. *When the image and container have different dimensions, the empty areas (either top/bottom of left/right) are filled with the background-color.*  The image is automatically centered unless over-ridden by another property such as background-position.